# Android run a piece of code each time the app is started but not when the app is minimised and reopened

Tags: android, lifecycle

Need to run a piece of code when the app each time the app is started and not while it is running or and not when main activity is navigated away from and returned to

just need to run the code once on when the app starts up

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about your actual use case, the only thing that I can suggest is -

- Override attachBaseContext() in your Application class (Create one
     if you don't have it)
- Call super.attachBaseContext()
- Write the code you need to run in the method body. (As always, for
  any
     long-standing or db/network operations, don't do it on the main
     thread)

attachBaseContext() is one of the first things to be called when your app is launched so I think this should work for you.

Comment: I am calling a webservice which updates the sql lite database if the user is connected to the internet, if they aren't then rest call and update aren't made, but i dont want it to run each time the app is "minimized" and the selected again